# PHP websocket is not updating after the content changes in the file

Tags: php, websocket

I am new to using websocket.

I want the script to update when the file.php content changes on the server. thats why I'm using '$previousContent' variable to get the primary content

```
$file = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/wwc/file.php';
$previousContent = file_get_contents($file);
```

Below in the script where the while (true) loop is found, I send a new request to find out if the 'file.php' content has changed and then I'm waiting for an update,
for this I use the following line :

```
$currentContent = file_get_contents($file);
if ($currentContent !== $previousContent)...
```

The complete code looks like this:

```
// Set server parameters.
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 33313;
$file = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/wwc/file.php';
$previousContent = file_get_contents($file);

// Create WebSocket server.
$server = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($server, $address, $port);
socket_listen($server);

// Create an array to store client sockets.
$clients = array();

// Function to perform WebSocket handshake.
function performHandshake($clientSocket) {
    // Read the client's handshake request.
    $request = socket_read($clientSocket, 5000);
    preg_match('#Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)\r\n#', $request, $matches);
    $key = base64_encode(pack(
        'H*',
        sha1($matches[1] . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')
    ));
    $headers = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
    $headers .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
    $headers .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
    $headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";
    $headers .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: $key\r\n\r\n";
    
    // Send the handshake response to the client.
    @socket_write($clientSocket, $headers, strlen($headers));
}

// Function to send file content to a specific client.
function sendFileContentToClient($content, $clientSocket) {
    $response = chr(129) . chr(strlen($content)) . $content;
    @socket_write($clientSocket, $response);
}

// Function to send file content to all connected clients.
function sendFileContentToAllClients($content, $clients) {
    $response = chr(129) . chr(strlen($content)) . $content;
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        @socket_write($client, $response);
    }
}
// Main server loop.
while (true) {
    // Check for new client connections.
    if ($newClient = socket_accept($server)) {
        // Perform WebSocket handshake with the client.
        performHandshake($newClient);
        
        // Store client socket in the array.
        $clients[] = $newClient;
        
        // Send the current file content to the newly connected client.
        sendFileContentToClient($previousContent, $newClient);
        
        // Print a message to indicate a new client connection.
        echo "New client connected.\n";
    }
    
    // Check if the file has been updated.
    $currentContent = file_get_contents($file);
    if ($currentContent !== $previousContent) {
        // Update previous content with the current content.
        $previousContent = $currentContent;   
        // Send the updated content to all connected clients.
        sendFileContentToAllClients($currentContent, $clients);
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

****UPDATED****
I forgot to write.

The content is only updated and I get new file data when a new user is added.
How do I get an update when a file changes?

If I wrote something unclear, I apologize in advance